# Mongoose find/findOne always returns null when filter is added

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have problem which has seriously been bothering for the past few days. I have `mongoose` setup for a `nodejs` project I have defined all the schemas and models as shown below

```
var studentSchema = new Schema({
    fullname: {type: String, required: true},
    student_id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    votingNo: {type: Number, required: true, unique: true},
    voted: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false}
});
var Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema, 'student');
```

I have exported the model and i'm using it in another module.
whenever I try query for results like so:

```
 model.Student.find({}, function (err, students) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(students);
});
```

I get results. But the moment I add a filter, like so:

```
model.Student.find({student_id: studentId}, function (err, students) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(students);
});
```

The result is always an empty array.

I've tried using `findOne()` but it's always returning null.

Comment: If you get records without any filter and when you add filter, then it does not return anything, means you dont have any matching records in db.

Comment: Have you checked directly in mongo console, does it working there ?

Comment: add a sample documents to your post that might help understand your query

Comment: I figured out the problem. It seems during the import of data, i had mismatched some columns. thats why the data never matched

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the queries like this

```
var Student = mongoose.model('Student');
Student.find({}, function (err, students) {
     console.log(err);
     console.log(students);
});
```

If it doesn't work, add this before your call to be sure that the database is open.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState); // Should not return 0
```

Hope it helps!